Flink SQL UDF that return Map<String, Object>
I need to write a flink udf that can return Map<String, Object>, how do I achieve this.
At best I could get output = @DataTypeHint(value = "MAP<STRING, STRING>", bridgedTo = MapData.class) working. This only return map<String, String>
I have need to return data like
{
  "cloudStatus": "UNREGISTERED",
  "lastLoginTimestamp": "Tue Jul 18 15:22:33 GMT 2023",
  "visibleSegments": ["one", "two"],
  "booleanValue": true,
  "intValue": 123,
  "floatValue": 456.67,
  "sysDescriptions": {
    "en_US": "ADFlatFile 015 entitlement0001 desc"
  },
  "list_of_list": [["one", "two"]],
  "list_of_map": [
    {
      "k2": true,
      "k1": 10,
      "k3": "v3"
    }
  ],
  "ou.location": "12334",
  "ou.position": "assd",
  "ou.operating.company": "abc_er",
  "member.value": "abc_er"
}


Input to the UDF is a json that represent similar data as above

It sounds like your UDF is going to take JSON and return JSON.  If there is no more of a schema to the input or output, then using Strings is probably your best bet.
If you are writing a Java program, you can map those Strings to your POJOs on either side of the processing.

I dont have a predefined schema, the map<String, Object> , here Object can be anything, string, int, pojo
